# Multidimensional Array Group By Similar Key/Value Pair

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [date] => August
    [mozrank] => 2
    [domain_authority] => 41
    [external_links] => 9
    [unique_visitors] => 14
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [date] => August
    [post_count] => 70
    [comment_count] => 53
    [theme] => yes
    [plugins] => 3
  )
  [2] => Array (
    [date] => September
    [mozrank] => 4
    [domain_authority] => 42
    [external_links] => 10
    [unique_visitors] => 20
  )
  [3] => Array (
    [date] => September
    [post_count] => 71
    [comment_count] => 56
    [theme] => yes
    [plugins] => 5
  )
)
```

You'll notice that there are two arrays that have the same key/value pair of August and two arrays that have the same key/value pair of September. However in each case they have different keys associated with them. I'm trying to group each array on the date key where the value is the same and merge the other keys together. For example, the output would be:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [date] => August
    [mozrank] => 2
    [domain_authority] => 41
    [external_links] => 9
    [unique_visitors] => 14
    [post_count] => 70
    [comment_count] => 53
    [theme] => yes
    [plugins] => 3
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [date] => September
    [mozrank] => 4
    [domain_authority] => 42
    [external_links] => 10
    [unique_visitors] => 20
    [post_count] => 71
    [comment_count] => 56
    [theme] => yes
    [plugins] => 5
  )
)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing that cross my mind:

```
$merged = array();
foreach ($array as $item)
{
    $date = $item['date'];
    if (!isset($merged[$date]))
    {
        $merged[$date] = array();
    }
    $merged[$date] = array_merge($merged[$date], $item);
}
```

As result there will be an array where key is a month. If you want standard index (begin from 0) you can always use `shuffle()`.

Result:

```
array (size=2)
  'August' => 
    array (size=9)
      'date' => string 'August' (length=6)
      'mozrank' => int 2
      'domain_authority' => int 41
      'external_links' => int 9
      'unique_visitors' => int 14
      'post_count' => int 70
      'comment_count' => int 53
      'theme' => string 'yes' (length=3)
      'plugins' => int 3
  'September' => 
    array (size=9)
      'date' => string 'September' (length=9)
      'mozrank' => int 4
      'domain_authority' => int 42
      'external_links' => int 10
      'unique_visitors' => int 20
      'post_count' => int 71
      'comment_count' => int 56
      'theme' => string 'yes' (length=3)
      'plugins' => int 5
```

P.S. I have feeling that it can be done better than this...